# ASP.NET login page loads very slow takes 30 secs

Tags: asp.net, mysql

We have ASP.NET Application in Test server. For first time access the Login page of that application load time is slow.  Response time is around 25-30 sec. After that I refershed the page or Opened with a new browser, loading of Login Page is around 1-2 sec.

Only user name & password columns are there in login page. Is there any way I can reduce the response time for first time loading?

underline db mysql. we are using godaddy virtual server windows.

Comment: Login page only is slow, or any first-time view of the application? Which authentication method are you using?

Comment: Did you create indexes? How are static resources loaded (through a script or directly)? How high is the server load?

Comment: Maybe it's busy compiling all the source files you put in `App_Code` instead of deploying a DLL to the `Bin` folder?

Comment: Posting some code would be helpful. No matter what, 25-30 sec load is not normal. I'm assuming that this load time happens whenever your application starts up (touch the Web.config to restart your app to confirm). Also make sure debug="false" in your Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

It's curious that this happens freshly in each browser. It makes me suspect one of the pages resources (css? image? javascript?) are loading slowly. Therefore, client side caching speeds up the load on the second time.

Have you tried using HttpFox? Or using Firebug to determine what step in loading the page causes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few tips, The first time you load an application it may take up to 30 seconds to "warm up".  Once loaded, it will fire much quicker.  The application will stay loaded into IIS memory as long as the application is continually hit (until IIS recycles itself, which by default happens once a day).

If you push a new build and\or change your web config, the application will automatically recycle itself as well.

If youre using IIS 7.5, it now offers a Warm Up Module, which will pretty much keep your application ready to go, even if its not hit very often, check out - http://www.iis.net/download/applicationwarmup